# how to enter ip in query linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

i have follwing query how to enter server IP in my query, please help me,

```
DECLARE @ScopeIdentity int;

    EXEC 175.120.124.162.Taxi.sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO [175.110.104.162].Taxi.dbo.booking (FromLocTypeId,ToLocTypeId,FromLocId,ToLocId,VehicleTypeId,DriverId,ReturnDriverId,CustomerId,CustomerName,CustomerEmail,CustomerPhoneNo,CustomerMobileNo,JourneyTypeId,BookingNo,BookingDate,NoofPassengers,NoofLuggages,NoofHandLuggages,PickupDateTime,ReturnPickupDateTime,IsCompanyWise,CompanyId,FareRate,PaymentTypeId,SpecialRequirements,FromAddress,ToAddress,FromPostCode,ToPostCode,FromDoorNo,ToDoorNo,FromStreet,ToStreet,FromFlightNo,FromComing,BookingStatusId,DistanceString,AutoDespatch,AutoDespatchTime,AddOn,AddBy,AddLog,EditOn,EditBy,EditLog,OrderNo,PupilNo,ParkingCharges,WaitingCharges,ExtraDropCharges,MeetAndGreetCharges,CongtionCharges,TotalCharges,DepartmentId,ReturnFareRate  
    ,ArrivalDateTime,MasterJobId,DisablePassengerSMS,DisableDriverSMS,IsCommissionWise,DriverCommission,DespatchDateTime,JobOfferDateTime,BookingTypeId,DriverCommissionType,IsBidding,IsQuotation,CostCenterId,CashRate,AccountRate,WaitingMins  
    ,ExtraMile,AcceptedDateTime,POBDateTime,STCDateTime,ClearedDateTime,CancelReason,TotalTravelledMiles,CompanyPrice,SubCompanyId,PartyId,
    FromOther,ToOther,TransferJobId,TransferJobCommission,BookingTypeId,ViaString) 

    SELECT   
    FromLocTypeId,ToLocTypeId,FromLocId,ToLocId,VehicleTypeId,null,ReturnDriverId,CustomerId,CustomerName,CustomerEmail,CustomerPhoneNo,CustomerMobileNo,JourneyTypeId,BookingNo,BookingDate,NoofPassengers,NoofLuggages,NoofHandLuggages,PickupDateTime,ReturnPickupDateTime,IsCompanyWise,null,FareRate,PaymentTypeId,SpecialRequirements,FromAddress,ToAddress,FromPostCode,ToPostCode,FromDoorNo,ToDoorNo,FromStreet,ToStreet,FromFlightNo,FromComing,BookingStatusId,DistanceString,AutoDespatch,AutoDespatchTime,AddOn,AddBy,AddLog,EditOn,EditBy,EditLog,OrderNo,PupilNo,ParkingCharges,WaitingCharges,ExtraDropCharges,MeetAndGreetCharges,CongtionCharges,TotalCharges,DepartmentId,ReturnFareRate
    ,ArrivalDateTime,MasterJobId,DisablePassengerSMS,DisableDriverSMS,IsCommissionWise,DriverCommission,DespatchDateTime,JobOfferDateTime,BookingTypeId,DriverCommissionType,IsBidding,IsQuotation,CostCenterId,CashRate,AccountRate,WaitingMins  
    ,ExtraMile,AcceptedDateTime,POBDateTime,STCDateTime,ClearedDateTime,CancelReason,TotalTravelledMiles,CompanyPrice,1,@PartyId
    ,FromOther,ToOther,@JOB_id,@Commission,10,ViaString

    FROM Booking  
    WHERE Id = @JOB_id  ;select SCOPE_IDENTITY()';
    SELECT  @ScopeIdentity;
```

IP address show me error how to enter linked server name, i want Scopeidentity,
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remote Stored Procedure can be called as four part name:

```
EXEC [RemoteServer] .DatabaseName.DatabaseOwner.StoredProcedureName
```

I am not sure why are you using dynamic SQL. Try like this.

```
DECLARE @ScopeIdentity INT;

INSERT INTO [175.110.104.162].Taxi.dbo.booking (
    FromLocTypeId
    ,ToLocTypeId
    ,FromLocId
    ,ToLocId
    ,VehicleTypeId
    ,DriverId
    ,ReturnDriverId
    ,CustomerId
    ,CustomerName
    ,CustomerEmail
    ,CustomerPhoneNo
    ,CustomerMobileNo
    ,JourneyTypeId
    ,BookingNo
    ,BookingDate
    ,NoofPassengers
    ,NoofLuggages
    ,NoofHandLuggages
    ,PickupDateTime
    ,ReturnPickupDateTime
    ,IsCompanyWise
    ,CompanyId
    ,FareRate
    ,PaymentTypeId
    ,SpecialRequirements
    ,FromAddress
    ,ToAddress
    ,FromPostCode
    ,ToPostCode
    ,FromDoorNo
    ,ToDoorNo
    ,FromStreet
    ,ToStreet
    ,FromFlightNo
    ,FromComing
    ,BookingStatusId
    ,DistanceString
    ,AutoDespatch
    ,AutoDespatchTime
    ,AddOn
    ,AddBy
    ,AddLog
    ,EditOn
    ,EditBy
    ,EditLog
    ,OrderNo
    ,PupilNo
    ,ParkingCharges
    ,WaitingCharges
    ,ExtraDropCharges
    ,MeetAndGreetCharges
    ,CongtionCharges
    ,TotalCharges
    ,DepartmentId
    ,ReturnFareRate
    ,ArrivalDateTime
    ,MasterJobId
    ,DisablePassengerSMS
    ,DisableDriverSMS
    ,IsCommissionWise
    ,DriverCommission
    ,DespatchDateTime
    ,JobOfferDateTime
    ,BookingTypeId
    ,DriverCommissionType
    ,IsBidding
    ,IsQuotation
    ,CostCenterId
    ,CashRate
    ,AccountRate
    ,WaitingMins
    ,ExtraMile
    ,AcceptedDateTime
    ,POBDateTime
    ,STCDateTime
    ,ClearedDateTime
    ,CancelReason
    ,TotalTravelledMiles
    ,CompanyPrice
    ,SubCompanyId
    ,PartyId
    ,FromOther
    ,ToOther
    ,TransferJobId
    ,TransferJobCommission
    ,BookingTypeId
    ,ViaString
    )
SELECT FromLocTypeId
    ,ToLocTypeId
    ,FromLocId
    ,ToLocId
    ,VehicleTypeId
    ,NULL
    ,ReturnDriverId
    ,CustomerId
    ,CustomerName
    ,CustomerEmail
    ,CustomerPhoneNo
    ,CustomerMobileNo
    ,JourneyTypeId
    ,BookingNo
    ,BookingDate
    ,NoofPassengers
    ,NoofLuggages
    ,NoofHandLuggages
    ,PickupDateTime
    ,ReturnPickupDateTime
    ,IsCompanyWise
    ,NULL
    ,FareRate
    ,PaymentTypeId
    ,SpecialRequirements
    ,FromAddress
    ,ToAddress
    ,FromPostCode
    ,ToPostCode
    ,FromDoorNo
    ,ToDoorNo
    ,FromStreet
    ,ToStreet
    ,FromFlightNo
    ,FromComing
    ,BookingStatusId
    ,DistanceString
    ,AutoDespatch
    ,AutoDespatchTime
    ,AddOn
    ,AddBy
    ,AddLog
    ,EditOn
    ,EditBy
    ,EditLog
    ,OrderNo
    ,PupilNo
    ,ParkingCharges
    ,WaitingCharges
    ,ExtraDropCharges
    ,MeetAndGreetCharges
    ,CongtionCharges
    ,TotalCharges
    ,DepartmentId
    ,ReturnFareRate
    ,ArrivalDateTime
    ,MasterJobId
    ,DisablePassengerSMS
    ,DisableDriverSMS
    ,IsCommissionWise
    ,DriverCommission
    ,DespatchDateTime
    ,JobOfferDateTime
    ,BookingTypeId
    ,DriverCommissionType
    ,IsBidding
    ,IsQuotation
    ,CostCenterId
    ,CashRate
    ,AccountRate
    ,WaitingMins
    ,ExtraMile
    ,AcceptedDateTime
    ,POBDateTime
    ,STCDateTime
    ,ClearedDateTime
    ,CancelReason
    ,TotalTravelledMiles
    ,CompanyPrice
    ,1
    ,@PartyId
    ,FromOther
    ,ToOther
    ,@JOB_id
    ,@Commission
    ,10
    ,ViaString
FROM Booking
WHERE Id = @JOB_id;

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: you may also need  to take into account,whether it is named instance/default instance..

Comment: I AM Direct calling Booking table name

Comment: SCOPE_IDENTITY RETURN NULL ,

Comment: @TheGameiswar SCOPE_IDENTITY RETURN NULL value

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @ScopeIdentity int;
declare @identity table (ids int )
insert into @identity
    EXEC ('INSERT INTO [175.110.104.162].Taxi.dbo.booking (FromLocTypeId,ToLocTypeId,FromLocId,ToLocId,VehicleTypeId,DriverId,ReturnDriverId,CustomerId,CustomerName,CustomerEmail,CustomerPhoneNo,CustomerMobileNo,JourneyTypeId,BookingNo,BookingDate,NoofPassengers,NoofLuggages,NoofHandLuggages,PickupDateTime,ReturnPickupDateTime,IsCompanyWise,CompanyId,FareRate,PaymentTypeId,SpecialRequirements,FromAddress,ToAddress,FromPostCode,ToPostCode,FromDoorNo,ToDoorNo,FromStreet,ToStreet,FromFlightNo,FromComing,BookingStatusId,DistanceString,AutoDespatch,AutoDespatchTime,AddOn,AddBy,AddLog,EditOn,EditBy,EditLog,OrderNo,PupilNo,ParkingCharges,WaitingCharges,ExtraDropCharges,MeetAndGreetCharges,CongtionCharges,TotalCharges,DepartmentId,ReturnFareRate  
    ,ArrivalDateTime,MasterJobId,DisablePassengerSMS,DisableDriverSMS,IsCommissionWise,DriverCommission,DespatchDateTime,JobOfferDateTime,BookingTypeId,DriverCommissionType,IsBidding,IsQuotation,CostCenterId,CashRate,AccountRate,WaitingMins  
    ,ExtraMile,AcceptedDateTime,POBDateTime,STCDateTime,ClearedDateTime,CancelReason,TotalTravelledMiles,CompanyPrice,SubCompanyId,PartyId,
    FromOther,ToOther,TransferJobId,TransferJobCommission,BookingTypeId,ViaString) 

    SELECT   
    FromLocTypeId,ToLocTypeId,FromLocId,ToLocId,VehicleTypeId,null,ReturnDriverId,CustomerId,CustomerName,CustomerEmail,CustomerPhoneNo,CustomerMobileNo,JourneyTypeId,BookingNo,BookingDate,NoofPassengers,NoofLuggages,NoofHandLuggages,PickupDateTime,ReturnPickupDateTime,IsCompanyWise,null,FareRate,PaymentTypeId,SpecialRequirements,FromAddress,ToAddress,FromPostCode,ToPostCode,FromDoorNo,ToDoorNo,FromStreet,ToStreet,FromFlightNo,FromComing,BookingStatusId,DistanceString,AutoDespatch,AutoDespatchTime,AddOn,AddBy,AddLog,EditOn,EditBy,EditLog,OrderNo,PupilNo,ParkingCharges,WaitingCharges,ExtraDropCharges,MeetAndGreetCharges,CongtionCharges,TotalCharges,DepartmentId,ReturnFareRate
    ,ArrivalDateTime,MasterJobId,DisablePassengerSMS,DisableDriverSMS,IsCommissionWise,DriverCommission,DespatchDateTime,JobOfferDateTime,BookingTypeId,DriverCommissionType,IsBidding,IsQuotation,CostCenterId,CashRate,AccountRate,WaitingMins  
    ,ExtraMile,AcceptedDateTime,POBDateTime,STCDateTime,ClearedDateTime,CancelReason,TotalTravelledMiles,CompanyPrice,1,@PartyId
    ,FromOther,ToOther,@JOB_id,@Commission,10,ViaString

    FROM Booking  
    WHERE Id = @JOB_id  ;select SCOPE_IDENTITY()') at 175.120.124.162

set @ScopeIdentity=(select top 1 ids  from @identity)
select @ScopeIdentity
```