# SQL SERVER LINKEDSERVER ERROR OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

i have following query its show error how to handle this please help me

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "125.144.124.145" returned message "Deferred prepare could not be completed.".

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_TransferJob]  
(  
  @JOB_id AS bigint,
  @PartyId as int,
  @Commission as decimal(18,2)
)  
AS
BEGIN  
 declare @ServerBookingId  bigint;

exec('  
INSERT INTO Taxi.dbo.booking (FromLocTypeId,ToLocTypeId,FromLocId,ToLocId,VehicleTypeId,DriverId,ReturnDriverId,CustomerId,CustomerName,CustomerEmail,CustomerPhoneNo,CustomerMobileNo,JourneyTypeId,BookingNo,BookingDate,NoofPassengers,NoofLuggages,NoofHandLuggages,PickupDateTime,ReturnPickupDateTime,IsCompanyWise,CompanyId,FareRate,PaymentTypeId,SpecialRequirements,FromAddress,ToAddress,FromPostCode,ToPostCode,FromDoorNo,ToDoorNo,FromStreet,ToStreet,FromFlightNo,FromComing,BookingStatusId,DistanceString,AutoDespatch,AutoDespatchTime,AddOn,AddBy,AddLog,EditOn,EditBy,EditLog,OrderNo,PupilNo,ParkingCharges,WaitingCharges,ExtraDropCharges,MeetAndGreetCharges,CongtionCharges,TotalCharges,DepartmentId,ReturnFareRate  
,ArrivalDateTime,MasterJobId,DisablePassengerSMS,DisableDriverSMS,IsCommissionWise,DriverCommission,DespatchDateTime,JobOfferDateTime,
DriverCommissionType,IsBidding,IsQuotation,CostCenterId,CashRate,AccountRate,WaitingMins  
,ExtraMile,AcceptedDateTime,POBDateTime,STCDateTime,ClearedDateTime,CancelReason,TotalTravelledMiles,CompanyPrice,SubCompanyId,PartyId,
FromOther,ToOther,TransferJobId,TransferJobCommission,BookingTypeId)

SELECT   
FromLocTypeId,ToLocTypeId,FromLocId,ToLocId,VehicleTypeId,null,ReturnDriverId,CustomerId,CustomerName,CustomerEmail,CustomerPhoneNo,CustomerMobileNo,JourneyTypeId,BookingNo,BookingDate,NoofPassengers,NoofLuggages,NoofHandLuggages,PickupDateTime,ReturnPickupDateTime,IsCompanyWise,null,FareRate,PaymentTypeId,SpecialRequirements,FromAddress,ToAddress,FromPostCode,ToPostCode,FromDoorNo,ToDoorNo,FromStreet,ToStreet,FromFlightNo,FromComing,BookingStatusId,DistanceString,AutoDespatch,AutoDespatchTime,AddOn,AddBy,AddLog,EditOn,EditBy,EditLog,OrderNo,PupilNo,ParkingCharges,WaitingCharges,ExtraDropCharges,MeetAndGreetCharges,CongtionCharges,TotalCharges,DepartmentId,ReturnFareRate
,ArrivalDateTime,MasterJobId,DisablePassengerSMS,DisableDriverSMS,IsCommissionWise,DriverCommission,DespatchDateTime,JobOfferDateTime,
DriverCommissionType,IsBidding,IsQuotation,CostCenterId,CashRate,AccountRate,WaitingMins  
,ExtraMile,AcceptedDateTime,POBDateTime,STCDateTime,ClearedDateTime,CancelReason,TotalTravelledMiles,CompanyPrice,1,'+ @PartyId +'
,FromOther,ToOther,'+ @JOB_id+ ', '+ @Commission+',10

FROM TAXI..booking  
WHERE Id ='+ @JOB_id +' SELECT ' + @ServerBookingId+'=SCOPE_IDENTITY()') at [125.144.124.145]


-----------------------------------------------------------------------  
INSERT INTO [125.144.124.145].Taxi.dbo.booking_ViaLocations (  
BookingId,ViaLocTypeId,ViaLocTypeLabel,ViaLocTypeValue,ViaLocId,ViaLocValue,ViaLocLabel  
)  

SELECT   
@ServerBookingId,ViaLocTypeId,ViaLocTypeLabel,ViaLocTypeValue,ViaLocId,ViaLocValue,ViaLocLabel  
FROM Booking_ViaLocations  
WHERE BookingId = @JOB_id  




update Booking set BookingStatusId=21,TransferJobCommission=@Commission,PartyId=@PartyId where Id=@JOB_id
END


GO
```

Comment: I cannot look at your codes in detail, but I doubt that having 2 SELECT statements simultaneously is not valid.

Comment: HOW T solve this problem

Comment: i was connected my server 125.144.124 its working fine

Answer (score 1):

If your inside query is correct , then you can try as follows(here = databasename,=schemaname)

```
exec('  
INSERT INTO Taxi.dbo.booking (FromLocTypeId,ToLocTypeId,FromLocId,ToLocId,VehicleTypeId,DriverId,ReturnDriverId,CustomerId,CustomerName,CustomerEmail,CustomerPhoneNo,CustomerMobileNo,JourneyTypeId,BookingNo,BookingDate,NoofPassengers,NoofLuggages,NoofHandLuggages,PickupDateTime,ReturnPickupDateTime,IsCompanyWise,CompanyId,FareRate,PaymentTypeId,SpecialRequirements,FromAddress,ToAddress,FromPostCode,ToPostCode,FromDoorNo,ToDoorNo,FromStreet,ToStreet,FromFlightNo,FromComing,BookingStatusId,DistanceString,AutoDespatch,AutoDespatchTime,AddOn,AddBy,AddLog,EditOn,EditBy,EditLog,OrderNo,PupilNo,ParkingCharges,WaitingCharges,ExtraDropCharges,MeetAndGreetCharges,CongtionCharges,TotalCharges,DepartmentId,ReturnFareRate  
,ArrivalDateTime,MasterJobId,DisablePassengerSMS,DisableDriverSMS,IsCommissionWise,DriverCommission,DespatchDateTime,JobOfferDateTime,
BookingTypeId,DriverCommissionType,IsBidding,IsQuotation,CostCenterId,CashRate,AccountRate,WaitingMins  
,ExtraMile,AcceptedDateTime,POBDateTime,STCDateTime,ClearedDateTime,CancelReason,TotalTravelledMiles,CompanyPrice,SubCompanyId,PartyId,
FromOther,ToOther,TransferJobId,TransferJobCommission,BookingTypeId)

SELECT   
FromLocTypeId,ToLocTypeId,FromLocId,ToLocId,VehicleTypeId,null,ReturnDriverId,CustomerId,CustomerName,CustomerEmail,CustomerPhoneNo,CustomerMobileNo,JourneyTypeId,BookingNo,BookingDate,NoofPassengers,NoofLuggages,NoofHandLuggages,PickupDateTime,ReturnPickupDateTime,IsCompanyWise,null,FareRate,PaymentTypeId,SpecialRequirements,FromAddress,ToAddress,FromPostCode,ToPostCode,FromDoorNo,ToDoorNo,FromStreet,ToStreet,FromFlightNo,FromComing,BookingStatusId,DistanceString,AutoDespatch,AutoDespatchTime,AddOn,AddBy,AddLog,EditOn,EditBy,EditLog,OrderNo,PupilNo,ParkingCharges,WaitingCharges,ExtraDropCharges,MeetAndGreetCharges,CongtionCharges,TotalCharges,DepartmentId,ReturnFareRate
,ArrivalDateTime,MasterJobId,DisablePassengerSMS,DisableDriverSMS,IsCommissionWise,DriverCommission,DespatchDateTime,JobOfferDateTime,
BookingTypeId,DriverCommissionType,IsBidding,IsQuotation,CostCenterId,CashRate,AccountRate,WaitingMins  
,ExtraMile,AcceptedDateTime,POBDateTime,STCDateTime,ClearedDateTime,CancelReason,TotalTravelledMiles,CompanyPrice,1,@PartyId
,FromOther,ToOther,344110,22.11,10

FROM <dbname>.<schemaname>.Booking  
WHERE Id = 344110  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()') at [125.144.124.145]
```

Comment: can you please tel me how to get scope_identity id in my local variable because i want use this id in other query

Comment: SCOPE_IDENTITY() is used to return last identity column value, to use it you should first select some id from table, then using select SCOPE_IDENTITY() will pass the latest id to be select. using SCOPE_IDENTITY() depends completely upon your requirement. If you could provide me you requirement, it would be easy for me to explain

Comment: please check my post.. i want scope_identity

Comment: Please check your post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39073286/how-to-enter-ip-in-query-linked-server/39079515#39079515

Comment: MSDTC on server 'ADEELKHAN-PC\MSSQLSERVER2K8' is unavailable.

Comment: Please provide me your qsn link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121552/discussion-between-ranjana-ghimire-and-addi-khan).